# about latest row in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have table like

- id
- name

When I inserted new row after that, I want to know which is the latest record in my table ..

How to write a query for this ? I don't want to use any primary key or timestamp or others

Can anyone answer this question ?

Comment: you want to know the last row inserted on your table without anything that can help you get that info, am I correct?

Comment: May as well say you want to know how fast your car is going and how far it went without a speedometer or odometer. Timestamps and incrementing PKs ARE THE TOOLS that you use to determine this information.

Answer (score 7):

> I don't want to use any primary key or timestamp or others

Sorry. The only reliable way is to store this information yourself.

Most commonly by storing some increasing value such as an `identity` generated value or sufficiently high precision timestamp as a column in every row. (which would be most suitable could depend on various factors - Should rows inserted in the same statement be treated as inserted simultaneously for example?)

SQL Server doesn't keep track of this information by default and you cannot rely on the rows being stored in insert order.

Comment: there is a recent similar question. You may want to answer that, too: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81697/best-way-to-get-the-most-recent-insert-from-a-table-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `id` column is an identity column and you want to retrieve the identity value of the record you just inserted, you can use the OUTPUT clause, like this:

```
INSERT INTO sometable (name)
OUTPUT inserted.id
VALUES ('some name');
```